# Polar Coordinate System Transform?

Tags: trigonometry, polar-coordinates

What is the fastest way (fewest trigonometric and square root operations) to transform between one radius and angle to that of a polar coordinate system with a different centerpoint? I.e. the polar equivalent of multiplying by the basis matrix in Cartesian coordinates to convert from one coordinate system to another?

E.g. some back of the napkin math - that I'm hoping there is a more efficient way to do - to transform A (with radius r and angle $\theta$) to S where the two centers are on the x axis separated by distance d (for simplicity the unit vectors of the two systems' 0 angles are assigned as (1, 0), and $r_A \leq d$):

$$ x_A = r_A\cos \theta_A \\
 y_A = r_A\sin \theta_A \\ 
 x_S = d + x_A \\
 y_S = y_A $$

$$ r_S = \sqrt{x_S^2 + y_S^2} \\
= \sqrt{(d + x_A)^2 + y_A^2} \\
= \sqrt{d^2 + 2dx_A + x_A^2 + y_A^2} \\
= \sqrt{d^2 + 2dr_A\cos \theta_A + r_A^2} $$

$$ \theta_S = \arctan \frac{y_S}{x_S} \\
= \arctan \frac{y_A}{d + x_A} \\ 
= \arctan \frac{r_A\sin \theta_A}{d + r_A\cos \theta_A}$$

Comment: I don't quite understand the math here.  What is A and what is S?  little a?  Is d distance?  Explain every variable you use or no one will be able to make sense of this.

Comment: Added more Latecization and defined some of the vars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to write a circle centered somewhere else other than the origin in polar coordinates is as follows:

$$r = r_0cos(\theta-\phi)+\sqrt{a^2-r_0^2sin^2(\theta-\phi)}$$

This is a circle of radius $a$ centered at the polar coordinate $(r_0,ϕ)$, and with $(r, \theta)$ representing any arbitrary point on the circle.  If you want to change location of the circle, simply swap in the new $(r_0,ϕ)$ values.

[Proof, a circle centered at the equivalent of cartesian coordinate (4,3)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widget/widgetPopup.jsp?p=v&id=8d8e2c27bcaa121d6ee0de4b98774bb4&title=Polar%20Graphs&theme=blue&i0=5%5Ccos%28%CE%B8%E2%88%92tan%283%2F4%29%29%2B%284%E2%88%9225%5Csin%20%5E2%28%CE%B8%E2%88%92tan%283%2F4%29%29%29%5E.5&i1=0&i2=2Pi&podSelect=&showAssumptions=1&showWarnings=11)

Comment: Hmm, so that's the relationship between r and $\theta$ for the circle. Are there equations other than mine to find the r and $\theta$ from an r and $\theta$ relative to the other circle?

Comment: You mean like using the new center of the circle as the origin and finding the distance of the old $r$ and $\theta$ to them?  I would just convert from polar to cartesian and find the distance, and then convert back.  PS accept my answer